# How to add objects from different rows of a Python list?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and to Python and am working my way through a script that modifies a list.  The first section below shows the list after importing from a file.

Where rows have the same [0][2][3] I would like to sum [4] from each row and sum [6] from each row.  Also change [2] to 'Sum'

The last section shows the end result, but after doing what I want in Excel, then importing the file.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

```
['4/1/2014', 'One', 'Buy', 'X', '33.333', '1.5', '50\n']
['4/1/2014', 'One', 'Buy', 'y', '14.348', '2.3', '33\n']
['3/27/2014', 'One', 'Buy', 'Z', '18.889', '0.9', '17\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Two', 'Buy', 'X', '6.667', '1.5', '10\n']
['3/27/2014', 'Four', 'Sell', 'Z', '2.222', '0.9', '2\n']
['3/27/2014', 'One', 'Buy', 'Z', '18.889', '0.9', '17\n']
['3/27/2014', 'Two', 'Buy', 'Z', '5.556', '0.9', '5\n']
['3/27/2014', 'Three', 'Buy', 'Z', '8.889', '0.9', '8\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Four', 'Sell', 'X', '16.667', '1.5', '25\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Four', 'Sell', 'y', '3.043', '2.3', '7\n']
['4/1/2014', 'One', 'Buy', 'X', '33.333', '1.5', '50\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Two', 'Buy', 'X', '6.667', '1.5', '10\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Three', 'Buy', 'X', '3.333', '1.5', '5\n']
['4/1/2014', 'One', 'Buy', 'y', '14.348', '2.3', '33\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Two', 'Buy', 'y', '11.739', '2.3', '27\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Three', 'Buy', 'y', '1.522', '2.3', '3.5\n']



['3/27/2014', 'Four', 'Sell', 'Z', '2.222', '0.9', '2\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Four', 'Sell', 'X', '16.667', '1.5', '25\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Four', 'Sell', 'y', '3.043', '2.3', '7\n']
['3/27/2014', 'Sum', 'Buy', 'Z', '33.333', '0.9', '30\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Sum', 'Buy', 'X', '43.333', '1.5', '65\n']
['4/1/2014', 'Sum', 'Buy', 'y', '27.609', '2.3', '63.5\n']
```

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: Is order of rows important or not? Do you expect the result to keep it or you can change it? Do you need to replace [2] to Sum or you expect creation of new line with sum?

Comment: I've got to the stage where I can import the file, change objects, sort it, create lists, append to lists based on the contents of various objects, and write the lists to files.  I've searched for solutions for the above challenge, but need some direction in what to study.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jan, a new line with [2] Sum and the summed values would be ok, I can append it to a the final list.  The order may not be important as I can sort it later.

Comment: Thank you saveman71, this worked very well.  My homework is now to understand it :)

Comment: One more question saveman71.  The real file that I am working with is larger and the result is 3 lists.  I need to run your code on each list separately.  For example to list1, then to list2, then to list3.  How can I do this?  Thanks again!!

Comment: Figured my last question out, thanks.

Comment: @user3579106 When talking to a user, add the `@` sign before, so it can be notified ! Thanks for marking the question as answered !

Comment: @user3579106: don't forget to accept saveman71's answer if it solved your problem — this is the golden rule of Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after many tries, i finaly made it to the result:

First, you will need to remove the duplicate data in your input (since your results not seem to not take into account duplicate data):

```
def is_duplicate(l1, l2):
    return not any(a != b for a, b in zip(l1, l2))

#remove duplicates

for i in range(len(li)):
    j = i + 1
    for x in li[i + 1:]:
        if is_duplicate(li[i], x):
            li.pop(j)
        j += 1
```

Then you create a list that will contain the output, and for each item in the list we pop it (remove from the list and stock it) then compare it to know if it have to be summed with others item. If so, we sum them and remove it so they won't be summed again.

```
out = []

while len(li):
    tmp = li.pop(0)
    i = 0
    while i < len(li):
        item = li[i]
        if tmp[0] == item[0] and tmp[2] == item[2] and tmp[3] == item[3]:
            tmp[1] = 'Sum'
            tmp[4] = '{:.3f}'.format((float(tmp[4]) + float(item[4])))
            tmp[6] = '{:.1f}\n'.format(float(tmp[6]) + float(item[6]))
            li.pop(i)
        else:
            i += 1
    out.append(tmp)
```

Sorry to give the answer directly instead of guiding you towards it.

Comment: This is very non-idiomatic Python... why `while` loops instead of `for` loops? Why `0` and `1` instead of `False`/`True`?

Comment: @ErikAllik : Sorry I learned to code in C, and i'm still learning Python. I'll modify this to make it more pythonic. For the `while` loops i can't find out how to make it with `for` loops, since the conditions have to be re-evaluated at each iteration due to the `pop()` operations.

Comment: for example something like `return any(a != b for a, b in zip(l1, l2))` would make a nice implementation for `is_duplicate` (or `itertools.izip` on Python 2.x if performance matters).

Comment: @ErikAllik Is there a way to replace the `while` loops with that implementation ? I'm interested...

Comment: `for i in range(len(li)):` for example where you're calling `is_duplicate`, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: And the inner `while j < len(li)` in the same block can be replaced by `for x in li[i + 1:]`, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @ErikAllik Your implementation of is_duplicate is wrong, you have to invert it for it to work as in `return not any(a != b for a, b in zip(l1, l2))`, modifying the answer

Comment: @ErikAllik Your modifications seems to work, I'm implementing them in the answer, thank you.

Comment: @saveman71: yeah, that's why I said `something like`... didn't test it. but thanks for pointing it out. Other than that, glad I could be useful :) btw you forgot to put in the `not any(...)` change. But I'll +1 anyway.